# How to install VMware 5.5 and higher on HP BL460c G6

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant, drivers, blade-server, iso

I have an HP ProLiant BL460c G6 with the HP NC532i Dual Port 10Gbe BL-c Adapter installed.  VMware won't install on this machine stating the network device is not found.  This happens with both the VMware-issued installer and the special HP edition of the VMware installer that expressly claims it works on the HP ProLiant BL460c G6.

I'm looking for advice from someone who has actually installed VMware ESXi onto an HP ProLiant BL460c G6 with the HP NC532i Dual Port 10Gbe network device.  Even better, I'd like advice from someone who has actually performed the process by which one creates their own VMware installer, preferably 5.5 or 6.0, which includes these "exotic" network drivers.  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: have you tried upgrading the firmware on the NIC cards ?

Comment: Although you're looking for advice from people with your specific issue I'm going to try to help even without that specific issue requirement. I ran into this issue with my setup on a different system for a realtek nic driver that 5.5 wouldn't support. This is the site I used to get it working: http://www.v-front.de/2014/12/how-to-make-your-unsupported-nic-work.html.

Comment: Thanks, Jon, I have tried that with other, unsupported hardware and it's a good idea to start.  I've decided to install something else on these blades.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this on more than one server? The reason I ask is that the 'vanilla' 5.5u2d ISO *definitely* works on a plain BL460c G6 because I've just installed it for this question on one of our old decommissioned blades. It had had the "2014 09" SPP firmware pack ran on it (2015 04) is out but I didn't bother with it but I can confirm it absolutely works without any extra drivers or whatever.

Comment: I will try that.  I suspect it's the 10 Gb ethernet blade that is causing this problem.  It might have been an optional component when this was produced.

Comment: FYI just spotted this; "Broadcom bnx2x driver version 1.60.50.v41.2 is supported with HP Virtual Connect (VC) with minimal NIC firmware v 5.2.7 and VC 3.1.0 on ESX 4.1 and newer
Tested with HP VirtualConnect. Get configuration from http://partnerweb.vmware.com/programs/hcl/ESX_Flex_config.pdf
HP's Virtual Connect (VC) Flex-10 technology has been tested with driver v1.52.12.v35.5 and VC v2.33." Worth checking right?

Comment: Thanks, I checked this out, but I've decided to install something else on these blades since it's so much trouble and I have a feeling this particular blade might have faulty hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The HP ProLiant BL460c G6 has an SD slot at the top of the blade.

I've installed the HP VmWare 5.5 image onto 3 x HP BL460c G6 using the sd slot.

Then you can setup the hdd's to be a datastore without wasting space for the hypervisor.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking about.  I was specifically asking about the drivers for the network controllers.